# Remove square brackets - scraping using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am scraping Google search result pages which are store in my own server. I am using the following code to scrape the page.

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace
import urllib2
import datetime
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import csv
today = datetime.date.today()
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.1.200/coimbatore/3BHK_flats_inCoimbatore.html_%94201308110608%94.html").read()

soup = Soup(html)
p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
aslink = soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class':'ac'})
for li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'g'}):
    sLink = li.find('a')
    sSpan = li.find('span', attrs={'class':'st'})
    print sLink['href'][7:] , "," + p.sub('', str(sSpan)).replace('.','')
print p.sub('', str(aslink)).replace('.','\n')
```

The problem here is I am getting this square brackets in my output

```
[No Pre EMI &amp; Booking Amount Buy Now , Get Best Deals On 1/2/3 BHK Flats! Over 50000+ New Flats for Sale, Starts @ 3000 per Sqft
 Enquire Us
 , Your Dream Villa For SaleIn Coimbatore
 Book a Visit!, Luxurious Properties In CoimbatoreBy Renowned Builder
 Booking Open!, Finest 2BHK Flats at its Best PriceAvailable @ Rs
2500/sqft Visit Now!, Properties for every budgetAnd location
 Explore Now!, Looking a 3BHK Flat In Alagapuram?Best Deal, Area 1598SqFt Book Now, Find 3 BHK Flats/Apts in Chennai
Over 200000 Properties
 Search Now!, Buy Flats With Finest Amenities InCoimbatore
 Elegant Club House
, 100% free classifieds
 Apartmentsfor sale/rent on OLX
 Find it now!]
```

This output is generated from the line

```
print p.sub('', str(aslink)).replace('.','\n')
```

I wanna know why is that bracket coming and I also wanna remove it.

**UPDATE**

Here is my page http://jigar.zapto.org/coimbatore/3BHK_flats_inCoimbatore.html_%94201308110608%94.html

Comment: You need to include the actual HTML that produces the results, noone can access your private server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findAll()` returns a list. If you wanted just one element, use `.find()` instead, which returns the first result:

```
aslink = soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'ac'})
```

The square brackets are the result of you calling `str()` on the list object. Alternatively, use an index to get one element out:

```
print p.sub('', aslink[0]).replace('.','\n')
```

or loop over `aslink` elements.

However, it looks as if you wanted to extract all text from the `span` element. Don't use a regular expression, just ask BeautifulSoup for all text content:

```
for l in aslink:
    print ' '.join(l.stripped_strings)
```

Comment: I want all the elements which falls in the condition

Comment: I am getting the following error `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'stripped_strings'
`

Comment: My last example assumes `aslink` is still a list; did you use `.find()` instead?

Comment: Yes I did use .find()

Comment: basically I am trying to pull out `href` from `<a>` and the span text from all ads as well as organic results. I hope my code is not that efficient enough!

Comment: @Venky: then call `' '.join(l.stripped_strings)` directly.