# Beautifulsoup remove bracket from output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get html from a web page:

```
try:
    description=hun.select('#description > div.tab-pane-body > div > div > div > table')
except:
    description=None

result = {"description":str(description)}

data.append(result)

print(json2xml.Json2xml(data, wrapper="all", pretty=True, attr_type=False).to_xml())
```

This works fine, but I have "`[<span>Test</span>]`" brackets in the output. How can I avoid these brackets from the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove square brackets - scraping using beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964584/remove-square-brackets-scraping-using-beautiful-soup)

Comment: `str.strip("][")`

Comment: didn't go deep but does this work ? data.append[1:-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be linked to "description" being a list. Otherwise you could use .text on the object to return the value as string.

```
try:
    description = hun.select('#description > div.tab-pane-body > div > div > div > table')[0].text
except:
    description = None
```

Comment: [0] did the trick, I didn't used .text at the end, because I want to get html content, not the text.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the element without bracket:

```
try:
    description = hun.select('#description > div.tab-pane-body > div > div > div > table')[-1]
except:
    description = None
```